# Copy all files with certain extension from all subdirectories from a portable device (which has no drive letter assigned)

Tags: networking, copy, usb

I've a cellphone connected as MTP to my computer (windows 7) and shows up as a 'Portable Device'. I want to copy all .apk files from all subdirectories of this device.

But using the search function of windows I can't copy from multiple directories and `xcopy` or `xxcopy` command line tools require my USB device to have a drive letter assigned. Which is not possible for a MTP connection (correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget the Portable Device of the USB option.

On phone

1. Download a server app such as [WebDAV Server](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theolivetree.webdavserver&hl=en). This mounts your
   phone roots directory over your local WiFi connection
2. Open app and start WebDAV server (mine: `http://192.168.1.113:8080`)

On pc

3. Assign a map network drive from the command prompt. Open `cmd.exe` and type `net use s: //192.168.1.113:8080` (this will assign drive letter `s` to the UNC path.
4. Stay in `cmd.exe` and use [xxcopy](http://xxcopy.com/xcpydnld.htm) to copy all `.apk` from all subdirectories from the device into one folder by the following command: `XXCOPY S:\*.apk  C:\myapks\   /SGN`. (the `SGN` command sorts the files, with newest files first)

downside: `DAV` is slow

sources:
[step 1 and 2](http://d0bon.blogspot.com/2014/07/map-drive-letter-to-android-mtp.html) - [step 3](http://www.howtogeek.com/118452/how-to-map-network-drives-from-the-command-prompt-in-windows/) - [step 4](http://www.xxcopy.com/xxcopy16.htm)